# How to generate twilio video calling link using REST API (without UI/UX) and share the link through email and join from browser

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-click-to-call

We are developing an utility where we need to generate the video calling link and share that video link to users where they can join from web browser directly without any web application. The documentation helps me to create room using /v1/Rooms POST API but there is no join API available in documentation which I can invoke whenever the user clicks the video calling link from the email.

Is this possible and any leads can be of great help!